# how to fix a 1/4 inch gap between the tub spout and the wall

Tags: bathtub, gap, spout

I have an issue with the tub spout not being flush with the tile wall. I've attached a picture that shows the problem. The spout is a slip on with a hex nut for tightening. The copper pipe coming out of the wall is 2 7/8 inches so I don't think it needs to be shortened. I've tried a different spout, but still have the gap. Also tried using a collar and spout, but still have the gap. Can anyone offer a suggestion, aside from a whole lot of caulk?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6jiN.jpg)
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRD1b.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your pipe is not coming out of the wall perpendicular to the wall. Since this is copper you may be able to square the nipple so it will not hit on the bottom like it is doing now.

Comment: Thanks. Now can you tell me how to square the nipple?

Comment: I would slide a piece of pipe over the nipple to give me some leverage I would probably leave 1/2 “ maybe 1” not covered and lift copper pipe will bend it will also kink if you are cautious getting it square even a little kink won’t leak.

Comment: Heating up the cooper pipe with a hair dryer with make it more pliable and easier to massage it up a little.

Comment: @EdBeal +1 for, nipple kink.  I knew i was not alone !